# Recursive Least squares (RLS) for mini batch

Tags: algorithms, least-squares, parameter-estimation, learning

I know that RLS  can be used to update parameters being learned as they arrive.
This can be done efficiently for single data point and the derivations are easily available online and also easy to understand.

However for my case I am looking for same equations when data arrive as a mini batch and not a single data point at a time. I could not find any material regarding RLS for mini batches.

According to my understanding the same equations can be also used by appropriately considering matrix dimensions. However I do not know if this is valid.

For my application I am considering a learning problem where I simulate a bunch of episodes say 'n' first and than carry out the least squares update.

Can anyone point me to where such material is available...

Comment: Did you think about using normal equations instead of matrices ?

Comment: from what I know...is to calc exact parameters for each mini batch ($\theta\hat$) and then to do some kind of an update rule to the main parameters for each theta using a learning parameter alpha...I guess this the way the to use the normal equation

Comment: Should the question be transferred to Signal Processing community?

Comment: I think it is easy if you update the inverse of the covariance matrix (it is just a sum). If you don't need the covariance matrix itself, it is ok because you don’t have to perform matrix inversion which could be slow if the matrix is large.

Otherwise you should use the Sherman-Morrison formula and in that case I don't think you can adjust it for minibatches in a vectorised way.